# How to set a Mac space that automatically show on the 2nd screen?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, osx-spaces, mission-control

Is there a way to assign a space per screen?
Let me explain - when I work with 2 screens I have windows on my main monitor and in my secondary monitor.
When I unplug from the secondary monitor I want to keep the same windows assignment I had on the 2 screens, and jump between using the 4 fingers in the touchpad.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Look at System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces. Is it checked or unchecked? Checked, this *might* be possible, unchecked it is not. Personally. I use it unchecked, as I have two displays permanently connected, so I'm not in my comfort zone with it checked & how that works.

Comment: I tested both options. If it's unchecked I can define a space for each monitor separately and put windows there, but when I disconnect the secondary display its space is not available and the windows jump to the primary display.
If it's checked, the other space can only be shown on the primary display.

Comment: It's supposed to drop the 'missing' Spaces back to the remaining display if you disconnect the other, then move them back again once you re-connect. I'm not sure why it isn't doing that.

Comment: It does drop them back to the remaining display, but to its main space while I want it to be the secondary space. In other words - I want to have a specific space that doesn't through windows out of it upon disconnection/connection of a secondary screen and that shows up on the secondary screen if exists.

Comment: If it's merging *windows* back into the main display, the you have the option *unchecked*. With it checked it should move the entire Space.

Comment: it's indeed unchecked and I can put it on screen2 space, but when I unplug the window jump to monitor1-space1 instead of monitor1-space2

Comment: Yes, that's correct behaviour. I said in my first comment you cannot get it to work with that unchecked. It must be checked, then the 2nd or subsequent Space can move between displays.

Comment: How can I bind the second space to the secondary display?

Comment: First, check that box, then reboot [You must have 'separate Spaces' enabled for this to work]. Invoke Mission Control - usually Ctrl ↑ by default, then bring your cursor to the top of the screen to open up the full detail. Drag a Space from one display to the other.

Comment: Doesn't help too. If I leave 1 space for each monitor, everything on the secondary monitor's space jumps to monitor1-space1 when I disconnect monitor2 and doesn't come back to monitor2-space1 when I replug it.
If there are 2 space on monitor 1 it behaves the same.

Comment: I think you need one more Space than you have displays - but this is not a mode I ever use, so I can't test it, sorry. There's also the possiility that displays are only enumerated at boot, not on the fly.